# How to Click and submit data by using Python

Tags: python, selenium

i am new in HTML and trying to click web button by using Pyhon.
on the button, i found below code.
probably after click button, then it send "send('97662','')"

```
 <a href="#" onclick="send('97662','')">Gone</a>
```

could you guide me how to do this?

this is my code. but it display

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: 
Unable to locate element: {"method":"class name","selector":"btn_decision"}
```

all the button name is same. but message is different.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.afteredu.kr/register/subscribe1.aspsubject_do=1.%EC%9B%94%EC%9A%94%EC%9D%BC%EC%98%81%EC%97%AD&inning=2018-3%EA%B8%B0')
elem = driver.find_element_by_class_name("btn_decision")
elem.click()
```

thanks for your advice in advance.

Comment: You have to click gone button

Comment: @Vince Update the question with the relevant HTML